# Как в Leaflet отрисовать маркеры через svg

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, svg, leafletjs

Столкнулся с проблемой отрисовки маркеров в react leaflet. leaflet заворачивает svg иконку в тег img, от чего мне нужно избавиться. В качестве иконки маркера может быть изогнутая стрелка. Нужно, чтобы тултип показывался при наведении на стрелку, а не при наведении на прозрачную область картинки.

```
{!!events.length && events.map(el => {
    if (!!excludedTypes && excludedTypes.includes(el.type)) return null;
    const iconPerson = new L.Icon({
      iconUrl: el.iconUrl,
      iconRetinaUrl: el.iconUrl,
      iconSize: [10 * zoom * 0.5, 12 * zoom * 0.5],
      className: 'Map-Event'
    });

    return (
      <Marker onclick={() => {
        setInfoblocks(el);
        setInfoblockId(el._id);
      }} key={el._id} icon={iconPerson} position={el.position}>
        <Tooltip direction='top' >
          <div>{el.title}</div>
        </Tooltip>
      </Marker>
    )
  })}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://github.com/iatkin/leaflet-svgicon?